# Check spreadsheet "X.xls" is open?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a simple way to check whether a particularly-named spreadsheet is open in the current Excel session, from VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       Dim wBook As Workbook 
             'Check that Summary worksheet is available for update.
 on error goto ErrHandler
            Set wBook = Workbooks("CommittedSummary.xls") 
               If wBook Is Nothing Then 
        msgbox("Not Open")
            Else 'It is open
                MsgBox("The 'CommittedSummary.xls' workbook is already in use and 
                cannot be updated.  Please try again when the workbook Is available", _ 
                vbCritical, "Committed Request Edit") : exit sub
               End If 
    errhandler: msgbox("Workbooks is already open"):exit sub
```

Comment: -1 (a) code fails if workbook is not open (b) `i` variable is not actually used (c) random `Goto Update` line

Comment: I have fix it. Sorry for the soon reply without notice it

Comment: You need error handling when testing if the workbook is open - if you add that I will remove the downvote

Comment: Add it before the 'set wbook' line. -1 removed

Answer (score 2):

Use error handling as below

```
Sub Working()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim strFile As String
strFile = "X.xls"
On Error Resume Next
Set Wb = Workbooks(strFile)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not Wb Is Nothing Then
MsgBox strFile & " is open in this Excel instance"
Else
MsgBox strFile & vbNewLine & " is Closed in this Excel instance", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `On Error Resume Next`

Just because the code will crashes at that line doesn't mean the workbook is not actually open.  It just means your code crashed.

If you have two instances of Excel.Application each instance with have a workbooks collection.  And might not be looking in the right workbooks collection.  Then your code will crash.  There could be other reasons why your code crashes.

Don't use Error handers in the normal flow of your code it's bad programming and it'll lead to problems.  Error handling is for problems that are unforeseen.

Comment: That is at odds with the majority view. Using error testing to detect whether an object exists is perfectly valid. And the OP did specify "current Excel session", your two instances comment is not valid.